How to show $\int_{-t}^{0}f(x+sb,t+s)ds = \int_{0}^{t}f(x+(s-t)b,s)ds$?
Sorry if this is obvious. Why is
$$\int_{-t}^{0}f(x+sb,t+s)ds = \int_{0}^{t}f(x+(s-t)b,s)ds?$$
Letting $u = t+s$ gives me
$$\int_{0}^{t}f(x+(u-t)b,u)du.$$
Any help is appreciated.

Note that $u$ is a dummy variable, so you can use $s$ instead of $u$.

But then wouldn't this just mean that $s=s+t$? @SineoftheTime

You can always rename variables bound by limits/integrals/sums/... Indeed, $\int f(x)dx = \int f(y)dy$. Effectively, it's $s_{\sf new} = s_{\sf old} + t$, and you could reuse the same variable $s$ as long as you avoid confusion.

Indeed, with the substitution $u = t + s$, we have
$$\int_{-t}^0 f(x+sb, t+s) \, \mathrm ds = \int_0^t f(x+(u-t)b, u) \, \mathrm du.$$
Let's have a think about what these characters actually mean. We have a function $f$, as well as variables $x, t, b$. Whatever this evaluates to, we are expecting it to contain $f, x, t$ and $b$, but not $u$. Why not? Well just like when we have a definite integral, say $\int_0^1 x^2 \, \mathrm dx = \frac 13$, the final answer does not contain $x$. It's what's called a dummy or free variable. (See, say, the Wikipedia page on free and bound variables.) A similar situation is when we have a sum, say $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac 12 n(n+1)$. The final answer contains $n$ but not $i$.
Since $u$ is a dummy variable here, we can call it whatever we like (as long as it doesn't conflict with a variable that already exists, like $x$, $t$ or $b$). So we indeed have \begin{align*}
\int_{-t}^0 f(x+sb, t+s) \, \mathrm ds &= \int_0^t f(x+(u-t)b, u) \, \mathrm du \\
&= \int_0^t f(x+(s-t)b, s) \, \mathrm ds
\end{align*}
by renaming $u \to s$.
